# i create 1 cookie in vb.net and save it but 2 cookies are created.why second cookie is created

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

i create http cookie named "user_status" then fill and add it in cookies.when i check cookies in browser then 2 cookies are available.one is my created cookie named "user_status" and other cookie (i'm not created) named "ASP.NET_SessionId"  is available.why this cookie(ASP.NET_SessionId) is created have randomly data.in the code Session("author_id") takes value from a function.

my code is:

```
    Dim c As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("user_status")
    c.Values.Add("Author_id_cookie", Session("author_id"))
    c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15)
    Response.Cookies.Add(c)
```

Comment: I found [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1491107.aspx?ASP+NET_SessionId+Cookie) online: "This cookie is automatically generated by asp.net. You do not have control over it. It is created the first time your application is accessed over the browser. You can enable Page tracing to see it or, you can get a tool similar to HTTPWatch to view it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cookie is used from the dotnet framework to maintain the session information for the user, if you have a session less appllication and don't want the cookie you can try to disable the session at the application level: https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/help/306996/how-to-disable-asp-session-state-in-asp-net